# Using CLT to calculate probability question

Tags: probability

Suppose $53$ percent of the population prefer red socks to green. If $100$ random people are asked, what is the probability that most (at least $50$) will say prefer GREEN:

So I set
\begin{align*}
N & = 49.5\\  
n & = 100\\  
p & = 0.47
\end{align*}

Then..
\begin{align*}   
P(N \geq 49.5) & = P\left(\frac{N - np}{\sqrt{npq}}\right)\\
               & \geq \frac{49.5 - 47}{\sqrt{100*.47*.53}}\\   
               & = \varphi(0.50)\\   
               & = 0.3085  
\end{align*}
Except, that's not the right answer. What did I do wrong in my calculations?

Comment: Please see this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: What is the "right answer" ?

Comment: Very similar to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1219685/what-is-the-probability-that-most-at-least-50-will-say-prefer-green

Comment: It's an assignment question from school.

Answer (score 1):

The "correct answer" using the binomial distribution is about $0.3078$ and you can find it with R using

`1 - pbinom(49, 100, 0.47)`

Your normal approximation with continuity correction giving $0.3085$ looks close enough, though my calculation suggests it could be $0.3082$ if you do not round in the middle of the caclution.

If the answer book is offering about $0.24134$ or $0.24157$ then it is using a different definition of "most".  If it offering about $0.27389$ then it is not using a continuity correction.

Answer (score 0):

Using CLT, the normal approximation to the binomial distribution will have mean $np$ and variance $np(1-p)$, where $n=100$ and $p=0.47$ (probability of people who prefer green).

What you want to find is $P(N\geq 49.5)$ (as a continuity correction of $-0.5$ needs to be applied) for the normal distribution, which will be
$$P(N\geq 49.5)=1-\Phi\left(\frac{49.5-47}{\sqrt{47(1-0.47)}}\right)=0.30822$$

Comment: @Mew You are right, as a continuity correction needs to be applied. I end up with nearly the same answer as what the OP had.